# Firebase Functions Deployment failing all of a sudden

Tags: google-cloud-functions

`There was an issue deploying your functions. Verify that your project has a Google App Engine instance setup at https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine and try again. If this issue persists, please contact support.`

`Error: Your project is being set up. Please wait a minute before deploying again.`
`Error: Process completed with exit code 1.`

Nothing that I'm aware of has changed in the code or the platform. There are currently seemingly unrelated issues on Google Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following troubleshooting options:

1. At the time of error, there was a Firebase issue that caused deployments to fail. It has already been rollbacked and you should now be able to successfully deploy your Firebase function
2. Try to update your firebase-tools to the latest version. `npm install -g firebase-tools`
3. Take a look at this [Serverfault post](https://serverfault.com/questions/1134469/google-firebase-cloud-functions-error-your-project-is-being-set-up-please-wai). Make sure that you initialize your storage bucket in your project. See [Cloud Storage for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start)
4. If the above options don't work, you can contact [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support) to further look into your case.